# Accepted answer alert for non-asker

Tags: feature-request, notifications, accepted-answer

<sup>Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I have not found an answer doing a few minutes of searching here on Meta.</sup>

---

Is there an easy way to set-up an auto-alert feature for "favorite" questions?

**What I want to achieve:**

- Quickly 'mark' questions of interest - *I can do this already with the regular fav star*
- Get a **notification** (email?) **when** a *fav'ed* question **gets a new *accepted* answer**

In particular:

- I do not want to get notified on *any* change to the question, just when an answer gets (newly) accepted.
- I do not want to set this up for a tag, but for a sub-group of questions to which I can quickly add/remove questions. (I *believe* the favorites would be the best way to go.)

Why?
Essentially, I want to be able to browse the site for interesting things - adding fav-stars as I go along - and then *not* be present for a while. Instead of *actively* checking all my favorites each time I get online, I would like some convenience.

Comment: There is [stack2rss](http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com/) which you could put a call to your favourites in to, but it looks like it strips pretty much everything from the rss so theres no way to know wether a question has been answered or not. The API call itself does tell you wether a question is answered though so it's definitely possible.